# Using RGB in AppDelegate yet colors do not match fully(Hex)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, colors, appdelegate

I am working on finalizing my app before I submit to the store.One issue that I am coming across is that the `RGB` that I am using is not holding true to the color that I am trying to show.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I want the below the search bar to be the color throughout the app, however Xcode is pushing the following HEX code: `#323A45` to a lighter grey then it should be.

Here is the actual color this should be: http://www.colorhexa.com/323a45

Finally, here is the code for my navigation bar:

The below code is in the appDelegate file

```
// Navigation Bat
      UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#323A45")
      UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
      UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

Hopefully I am just missing something. I have also used the color codes divided by 255. Ex. 45/255 55/255 etc. with the same result as you are seeing.

Can you help me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: use the RGB value instead?

Comment: How would I write that as an example? UINavigationBar.appearence().RGB?

Comment: are you using objective c or swift?

Comment: I am using Swift, and trying to make a global change through the app-delegate if possible

Comment: Bumping this thread to see if anyone else has seen this issue befor

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 39.0 / 255.0, green: 46.0 / 255.0, blue: 56.0/ 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

I have added the colour you provided, please try it and confirm.

## EDIT

Please do this too-
[image]

Comment: are you running it in simulator? please run it in an actual device.

Comment: what is the navigation bar in the view controller, in storyboard? please see to it that it is set to OPAQUE

Comment: I just changed all the VC's to that setting and it still shows the old gray color

Comment: how about changing the navigation controller's settings

Comment: What specifically would you like me to change?

Comment: select the navigation controller and change the settings in the storyboard as the picture in the edit.

Comment: I have copied your settings to the T and it still shows the old gray color